# How to make a scalene triangle, ie: rocket fins

Tags: modeling

So, I want to make a **scalene triangle** (3 sides all have different dimensions, and it has to have a thickness) to "weld" to a rocket body I've created. I've done the make a circle with three points thing, but it doesn't work for thinness or varied dimensions on the long axis. Least for me. Tried the join two cubes method, but then I'm left with a thick edge I can't control. Attempted to cut out triangles out of a square...No luck so far. Essentially my goal is to make four triangles, 135mm (the straight edge) X 21mm X 137mm, and have it be 2mm thick. Rocket fins. Then join them to the rocket body (cylinder) at 90 degree intervals. To print and hang off my RC A-10 and shoot off with an A series Estes rocket.

Comment: There are dozens of ways to get a triangle with the dimensions you need... I would highly recommend you do some basic modelling tutorials about things like box modeling, polygonal modeling... also for joining them around the rocket body there are different methods.

Comment: Is this a right-angled triangle? Is the body of your rocket cylindrical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way if you have the shipped with Blender addon Add Mesh: Extra Objects activated.

Add a single vertex. Make sure that vertex mode is selected after the vertex is added:

[image]

[image]

Extrude the vertex 135mm on Y axis and extrude the original vertex 21mm on the X axis. Have Vertex Snapping and Auto Merge Vertices turned on:

[image]

Extrude the vertex at 21mm to the upper vertex to complete the triangle:

[image]

Press F to fill the triangle. Also check face orientation:

[image]

You can either select the face and extrude it upward 2mm or, in Object mode add a Solidify modifier. Set the 2mm thickness and you might want to set the offset to 1.0 to have the object origin on the bottom of the corner before applying the modifier:

[image]

This is what you get:

[image]

Comment: Or without the need of snapping or extra objects: take the default cube in _Edit Mode_, select all with A, M to merge at center. Extude in Y direction and in X direction like you did, then A to select all and then F. Triangle completed.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks! I always manage to find the more convoluted way. If you want to post your better solution as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: No, not really. I actually think there are so many ways to get a triangle with certain dimensions and then to place it four times around the rocket body afterwards that this is rather a question to be closed for drawing opinion-based answers since there is not a single correct answer. And honestly, if someone had done just a few beginner tutorials on basic modeling I cannot believe that the OP has tried different methods and did not get any result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Geometry Nodes

[image: img0]

[image: img1]

You can make various shapes by changing these values also and it's 3D printable.

[image: img2]

[image: img3]
[image]